# How to set up a train schedule content type in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I'm trying to set up a site in Drupal 7 to list train schedules.

My concept is this: create a content type to manage each train.  I'm setting up each train like an airplane flight.  Each train leaves station A at a certain time, stops at a few other stations and ends at station X.

The content type needs to be able to handle which stations it will stop at (Taxonomy terms since values will be re-used) &  what time it will stop at each station.

As I said, the station names can be Taxonomy terms but I'm having trouble with the times.  While station names can be re-used, times each train stops at each station will vary.

Is there a module that will allow me to select a taxonomy term (individual station) and then allow an additional field to be edited on-the-fly to input a time?

I'm also open to alternative suggestions for setting this up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This post is pretty old at this point, so it may no longer be an issue for you, but I'll try to answer it anyway.

The type of solution I'm imagining for this is what the [Double Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/double_field) module sounds like it does (though I cannot be certain since I have never used it). *If* this module would be able to do it, you'd want a field with taxonomy with a Date field to select the stop and time of that stop (and then be able to have multiple values for this field so you can select multiple stops and their times).

Otherwise, you *could* use Taxonomy if the trains have set times that they arrive (like they always arrive on the hour, quarter after, etc.). Otherwise, yeah, it wouldn't be realistic to use that if they can arrive at 12:53, 3:38 - if any time is possible.